# Can I define multiple variables in JavaScript which rely on one another?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find out whether the following code will always work (in all implementations of JavaScript) and also whether there are any concerns with using it:

```
var query = window.location.search.substring(1),
    vars = query.split('&');
```

Basically, will the JS engine always process variables in the order in which they are defined in the JS?

I am using the query variable elsewhere, otherwise I would simply define vars as

```
var pairs = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
```

In general, are there any 'concerns' about both defining a variable and assigning a value to it in one fell swoop, especially where it comes to more complex assignment?

Comment: Should work all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no concern, you can use it when you define it - there will be no problem.
JavaScript hoists variables. Whenever you define a variable, it will move it up to the top of the current function. To illustrate

```
(function(){
    foobar = 3; // doesn't throw, since foobar was in a var statement, although it's later
    if(false){
         var foobar = 5;
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no harm in using multiple variables. You can declare and assign it.only thing keep in mind when going for complex assignment declare as and when needed.